# PowerShell Robo Copy File Transfer Progress

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I currently have a working Robo Copy function that tracks the percentage of the current file being transferred. I have been trying to get it to track the number of files transferred out of the total, for example, 10/50 files transferred. I have tried Trevor Sullivan's way for the progress, but it is not working with my script.

Here is a segment:

```
Function global:music_Transfer{

if($WPFmusic_checkBox.IsChecked -eq $true){

$quotation = ":"  
$source = "$DLetter$quotation\Users\$associd\Music"
$destination = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Music"
$copy = "/COPY:DTO"
$files = "*.*"
$backup = "/B"
$reportextrafiles = "/X"
$verboseoutput = "V"
$fullpathname = "FP"
$mirror = "/MIR"
$backupmode = "/ZB"
$subfolders = "/E"
$Retries = "/R:2"
$consolewrite = "/TEE"

robocopy.exe $source $destination $files $backup $reportextrafiles $verboseoutput $fullpathname $mirror $backupmode $subfolders $Retries $consolewrite | ForEach-Object -Process {
    $data = $_.Split([char]9);
    if (($data.Count -gt 4) -and ("$($data[4])" -ne ""))
    {
        $file = "$($data[4])"
        Write-Progress "Percentage $($data[0])" -Activity "Music" -CurrentOperation "$($file)" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue; 
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Progress "Percentage $($data[0])" -Activity "Music" -CurrentOperation "$($file)"
    }
}
# Robocopy has a bitmask set of exit codes, so only complain about failures:
[int] $exitCode = $global:LastExitCode;
[int] $someCopyErrors = $exitCode -band 8;
[int] $seriousError = $exitCode -band 16;
if (($someCopyErrors -ne 0) -or ($seriousError -ne 0))
{
    Write-Error "ERROR: robocopy failed with a non-successful exit code: $exitCode"    
}
}
}
```

It tracks what is being transferred and the progress of individual files, but not total files. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

not tested, but something along these lines may work

```
Function global:music_Transfer{

if($WPFmusic_checkBox.IsChecked -eq $true){

$quotation = ":"  
$source = "$DLetter$quotation\Users\$associd\Music"
$destination = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Music"
$copy = "/COPY:DTO"
$files = "*.*"
$backup = "/B"
$reportextrafiles = "/X"
$verboseoutput = "V"
$fullpathname = "FP"
$mirror = "/MIR"
$backupmode = "/ZB"
$subfolders = "/E"
$Retries = "/R:2"
$consolewrite = "/TEE"

$files = [array][System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($source, '*.*', 'AllDirectories')
$index = 0
$total = $files.Count
$starttime = $lasttime = Get-Date

robocopy.exe $source $destination $files $backup $reportextrafiles $verboseoutput $fullpathname $mirror $backupmode $subfolders $Retries $consolewrite | ForEach-Object -Process {
    $index++
    $currtime = (Get-Date) - $starttime
    $avg = $currtime.TotalSeconds / $index
    $last = ((Get-Date) - $lasttime).TotalSeconds
    $left = $total - $index
    $WrPrgParam = @{
        Activity = (
            "music_Transfer $(Get-Date -f s)",
            "Total: $($currtime -replace '\..*')",
            "Avg: $('{0:N2}' -f $avg)",
            "Last: $('{0:N2}' -f $last)",
            "ETA: $('{0:N2}' -f ($avg * $left / 60))",
            "min ($([string](Get-Date).AddSeconds($avg*$left) -replace '^.* '))"
        ) -join ' '
        Status = "$index of $total ($left left) [$('{0:N2}' -f ($index / $total * 100))%]"
        #CurrentOperation = "FILE: $file"
        PercentComplete = $index / $total * 100
        Id = 1
    }
    Write-Progress @WrPrgParam
    $lasttime = Get-Date

    $data = $_.Split([char]9);
    if (($data.Count -gt 4) -and ("$($data[4])" -ne ""))
    {
        $file = "$($data[4])"
        Write-Progress "Percentage $($data[0])" -Activity "Music" -CurrentOperation "$($file)" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue; 
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Progress "Percentage $($data[0])" -Activity "Music" -CurrentOperation "$($file)"
    }
}
# Robocopy has a bitmask set of exit codes, so only complain about failures:
[int] $exitCode = $global:LastExitCode;
[int] $someCopyErrors = $exitCode -band 8;
[int] $seriousError = $exitCode -band 16;
if (($someCopyErrors -ne 0) -or ($seriousError -ne 0))
{
    Write-Error "ERROR: robocopy failed with a non-successful exit code: $exitCode"    
}
}
}
```

Comment: I tried to work the function in, but it kept returning the errors or not calculating the files right. Any other ideas?

Comment: try replacing the `$files = ` with this: `$files = dir $source -recurse -file`

Comment: I think that fixed that, any ideas on the "Cannot bind parameter 'Activity' because it is null?

Comment: change `Activity =` to `Activity = 'testing'` to see if that works and go from there

Comment: After playing around with it a bit, it just returns "The hash literal was incomplete". The parameter structure looks fine however, i find it a little odd.